# Preloading images with javascript Image() elements sitewide in <head>?

Tags: javascript, image, resources, preload

I made a small preloading script to preload some mouseover icons in the footer of a website I was working on, but I was wondering, once a resource like an image is loaded, will it persist sitewide? I wanted to, once all other loading is done, work on preloading the images for the gallery page so when someone visits the gallery it doesn't have to load them on demand. If I write some javascript to preload all the images in a particular folder, will most browsers recognize that those resources are the same ones specified in another page? For instance if i do

```
var preloader = new Image();
preloader.src = "/wp-content/..../galleryimage1.jpg";
```

in the frontpages header, when they go to the gallery will it still have that image resource downloaded and recognize it as the same resource (assuming the browser cache hasn't been somehow cleared in between)?

EDIT: I expanded the script to recurse the upload directories of the site (it's wordpress) and load images after the page is loaded

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
            var images = new Array()
            function preload() {
                for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                    images[i] = new Image()
                    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                }
            }
            preload(
                <?php 
                    //recurse the directory structure of "uploads" to find all normal image files
                    $dash_Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path/to/wp-content/uploads/");
                    $dash_Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dash_Directory);
                    $dash_Images = new RegexIterator($dash_Iterator, '/^.+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
                    $dash_js_image_list = "";
                    //build js object to be loaded into preload() on $(window).load which occurs after entire page has been loaded
                    foreach($dash_Images as $Image=>$object){
                        $dash_js_image_list .= '"'.$Image.'",'."\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t";
                    }
                    //remove the last comma and indentations to preserve syntax in js
                    echo substr($dash_js_image_list,0,-9);
                ?>)
        });
```

is this script safe? is it useful? what should I do?

Comment: If the users hasn't disabled cache within the browser or cleared the caceh, those images should still be available from cache. But why preload images that (some or many) users will maybe never use? It's only useful if they're on the gallery page...

Comment: Well what I'm going to do is start loading the images for the sub-galleries once the user enters the gallery page, but I want to see if it will actually work first.